# Export to excel sharepoint 2013

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Export to Spreadsheet" option is available only in the default page where we view all the list items.

But i need to export a particular list item i.e. after clicking on the particular list item's Title it will open the detail information of that list item in dispform.aspx. I need to have export functionality in this page

Answer (score 0):

You could use below library to create excel file dynamically.

https://github.com/jsegarra1971/MyExcel

To access SharePoint data, use JSOM or REST api.

[jsom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-javascript-library-code-in-sharepoint)

[REST api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-rest-endpoints)

Comment: Hi,thanks but is there any out of the box feature for sharepoint

Comment: No OOB function in display view per my knowledge.